# Rails activity notification system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked around StackOverflow at seemingly similar questions but nothing really seems to fit the bill.

I have a couple models that I would like users to be able to subscribe and unsubscribe to. If a user is subscribed to a video for example, they will receive notifications for things like comments.

I like the look of Github's [notifications](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/) api which is built on rails but I can't seem to wrap my head around how I might replicate a similar architecture with my own models and controllers.

Please read the page I linked to above to the Github notifications API. If you think you can piece together how you might replicate this in rails please post some pseudo code of the models and the relationships they have to one another!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with them, but I'd start your research here:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Rails_Activity_Feeds